# windows command line windows closes after excution

Tags: windows

I've written a commandline program p.exe

1: I want to assign Ctrl+F2 to launch the program

2: I want the windows to remain open when the program finishs

How can I do these ?

Comment: 2. can be achieved by wrapping the exe in a batch file

Comment: I've put it in a p.bat but the window still disappears

Comment: Ofcourse the batch file must end with `@pause`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a text file with something like:

   ```
   cmd /k ipconfig
   ```

   Save this to launcher.bat or whatever you want to call it.
2. To create the keyboard shortcut, make a regular Windows shortcut (right click, drag, and drop or right-click and select "Create Shortcut")
3. Right click on the created shortcut, and select properties, where you can then assign a shortcut key.

The /k is the magic that keeps the command prompt open . . .

Comment: i've bind it to a key but no response. do i need to log out ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to log out.  What version of windows?  My guess would be the shortcut you've used is already in use . . .

Comment: windows 7 i've tried a few , none works

Comment: Does your batch file work when you double click on it?

Comment: actually the shortcut for .exe works. but shortcut for .bat doesn't

Comment: ok got it: in the target tab i've put: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k  C:\Windows\p.exe